# Map() in python gives output once only

Tags: python, python-3.x

I was playing with map() function in Python 3.6.3 when I came across this below situation ::

```
>>> a = [12, 23, 13, 14, 15, 36]
>>> b = [34, 45, 35, 32, 34, 34]
>>> c = [34, 67, 89, 98, 98, 78]
>>> map(lambda x,y,z:x+y+z, a,b,c )
<map object at 0x0000017DD976EC88>
>>> e=map(lambda x,y,z:x+y+z, a,b,c )
>>> list(e)
[80, 135, 137, 144, 147, 148]
>>> list(e)
[]
```

My question is that why I cannot get output when I used `list(e)` second time. It's showing empty list.

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I iterate twice over the same data with a given iterator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25336726/how-can-i-iterate-twice-over-the-same-data-with-a-given-iterator)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because In Python 3, **map** returns an iterator, which you can only iterate over once. If you iterate over an iterator a second time, it will raise **StopIteration** immediately, as though it were empty. Thats why you get empty list second time when you call it.
For more info see this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21715268/9400024)

I hope this helps you! :)